# How to combine a 'for' loop with an 'if' statement?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I am a newbie, and my question is probably the easiest many of you can imagine. Still, I am stuck, and been looking for answers everywhere, so please help. I am writing a simple loop, consisting of a 'for' and an 'if' statement, evaluating a simple vector. I keep getting wrong results and I do not know where the problem is. Here is the code:

```
Y <- c(3,5,2,7)  
for (n in Y) {
if (n < 6) (Y[n]=0)
}
```

When evaluated, the result is: 3 0 0 7 0, which is NOT what I am expecting! The code is supposed to evaluate every item in Y and return 0 if it is less than 6. So it should be: 0 0 0 7. What am I doing wrong? Please help!

Comment: Please tag your programming language.

Comment: why for loop and if else for this simple operation.  do this `Y[Y <6] = 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `for (n in Y)` you are actually iterating over the elements of your array, so when you try to change the value of Y, you're not passing the index but are passing the value.

You need to do something like this (don't know which language you're using):

```
Y <- c(3,5,2,7)  
for (n in 1:length(Y)) {
  if (Y[n] < 6) (Y[n]=0)
}
```

With your original code what's happening is:

```
if (3 < 6) (Y[3]=0) --it changes position 3
if (5 < 6) (Y[5]=0) --it adds a 0 to position 5
if (2 < 6) (Y[2]=0) --it changes position 2
if (7 < 6) (Y[7]=0) --nothing happens
```

Comment: It is written in R!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Out of curiosity: what exactly happened when I'd entered the original code? Why this bizarre result: 3 0 0 7 0 ?

Comment: @adalbehrt You were indexing `Y` with its own contents, so that was equivalent to `Y[3] = 0; Y[5] = 0; Y[2] = 0`. `Y[1]` and `Y[4]` remained untouched.

Comment: `if (3 < 6) (Y[3]=0) --it changes position 3
if (5 < 6) (Y[5]=0) --it adds a 0 to position 5
if (2 < 6) (Y[2]=0) --it changes position 2
if(7 < 6) (Y[7]=0) --nothing happens`

Answer (score 1):

As R is a vectorized language, `for` loops are rarely needed, especially for basic operations. Getting acquainted with the vector features of R can save a lot of typing (and headaches). So, for replacing all values in `Y` which are less than 6 we can write

```
Y[Y < 6] <- 0
Y
```

> [1] 0 0 0 7

Here, `Y < 6` returns a logical vector of those elements of `Y` which fulfill the condition

> [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

and which are then used for subsetting.

---

Furthermore, R has the `replace()` function which can be used likewise:

```
replace(Y, Y < 6, 0)
```

> ```
> [1] 0 0 0 7
> ```

Comment: Even if this doesn't answer the question, for the R developer is a much better solution to the problem the OP is trying to solve.